# DWB planner in Nav2 does not properly set scale for critics

Tags: ros-humble, nav2

[image]

ROS2 Humble. The above image is the output from the /evaluation topic published by the planner.
As you can see, the only critic with the correct scale is RotateToGoal, the rest are low for some reason. A result of this is that the robot does not stick to the path well. I am not sure if this is how it is meant to be or if this is a bug. Here are my FollowPath params:

```
# DWB parameters
FollowPath:
  plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
  #plugin: "nav2_rotation_shim_controller::RotationShimController"
  #primary_controller: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
  
  #rotate_to_heading_angular_vel: 5.0
  #max_angular_accel: 10.0
  
  debug_trajectory_details: True
  min_vel_x: 0.0
  min_vel_y: 0.0
  max_vel_x: 0.4 #0.3-0.5
  max_vel_y: 0.0
  max_vel_theta: 1.0
  min_speed_xy: 0.0
  max_speed_xy: 0.4
  min_speed_theta: 0.0
  # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
  # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
  acc_lim_x: 2.0 #2.5
  acc_lim_y: 0.0
  acc_lim_theta: 3.2
  decel_lim_x: -2.5
  decel_lim_y: 0.0
  decel_lim_theta: -3.2
  vx_samples: 20
  vy_samples: 0
  vtheta_samples: 40
  sim_time: 1.0
  linear_granularity: 0.05
  angular_granularity: 0.025
  transform_tolerance: 0.2
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.05
  trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
  short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
  stateful: True
  critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
  BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
  PathAlign.scale: 32.0
  PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
  GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
  GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
  PathDist.scale: 32.0
  GoalDist.scale: 24.0
  RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
  RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
  RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0
```

Can anybody replicate this?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Redstone. `RotateToGoal` and `BaseObstacle` are both reflecting what you have in the config you posted, but the other values obviously are different. I'm wondering if you're referencing the config you think you're referencing? If you change the `RotateToGoal.scale` in the file you copy/pasted from, do you see that change in your output? How are you referencing this file (and is it saved?) and what is the path to this file?

Comment: I think I've figured it out, I chose 0.3 and the output was .00375 so it is dividing whatever number is there by 80. Furthermore, the exact same params set in a sim work fine and in real life don't work out fine, so I think my problem is something else.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it divides the critics (except for RotateToGoal and Oscillation) by 80.

Comment: Do you know *why* it's dividing by 80?